# Initialization cycle error

Tags: go

I have autogenerated code. Simplified version:

```
package main

// begin of A
func main(){
    ParseReader("x")
}
func parseInclude(fileName string) (interface{}, error) {
    got, _ := ParseReader(fileName)
    return got, nil
}
// end of A
type grammar struct {
    pos   int
    run  func(*parser) (interface{}, error)
}
var g = &grammar{
    pos:  1,
    run: (*parser).callonIncludeOp1,
}

type parser struct {
    filename string
    cur      current
}
func (p *parser) callonIncludeOp1() (interface{}, error) {
    return p.cur.onIncludeOp1("x")
}
func (p *parser) parse(g *grammar) (val interface{}, err error) {
    return g.pos, nil
}

type current struct {
    pos  int 
}
// B
func (c *current) onIncludeOp1(qfilename interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    got, _ := parseInclude("x")
    return got, nil
}

func ParseReader(filename string) (interface{}, error) {
    p := &parser{ filename: filename }
    return p.parse(g)
}
```

I have error after compiling

```
./prog.go:19: initialization loop:
    /home/gCDfp4/prog.go:19 g refers to
    /home/gCDfp4/prog.go:25 (*parser).callonIncludeOp1 refers to
    /home/gCDfp4/prog.go:36 (*current).onIncludeOp1 refers to
    /home/gCDfp4/prog.go:7 parseInclude refers to
    /home/gCDfp4/prog.go:41 ParseReader refers to
    /home/gCDfp4/prog.go:19 g
```

I need do recursive call at grammar because i have preprocessor operator "#include" for parsing other file.

Because it is autogenerated code i can only modify code in block A or in function B.

How can i break the initialization cycle ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the result of the [package initialization](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_initialization) where:

> Dependency analysis does not rely on the actual values of the variables, only on lexical references to them in the source, analyzed transitively.
>
> For instance, if a variable `x`'s initialization expression refers to a function whose body refers to variable `y` then `x` depends on `y`.
>
> As in: "A reference to a variable or function is an identifier denoting that variable or function."

Your [example in a playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ShVU2hVoLa) returns something more direct:

```
tmp/sandbox395359317/main.go:21: initialization loop:
    prog.go:21 g refers to
    prog.go:28 (*parser).callonIncludeOp1 refers to
    prog.go:21 g
```

There are [techniques in Go for loose coupling](https://8thlight.com/blog/javier-saldana/2015/02/06/loose-coupling-in-go-lang.html), for instance **interface**.

As an example (not optimal, but at least breaks the initialization cycle), you can in `//A` add:

```golang
type parseIncluder interface {
    parseInclude(fileName string) (interface{}, error)
}

func (c *current) parseInclude(fileName string) (interface{}, error) {
    return parseInclude(fileName)
}
```

And in `//B`, the call to `parseInclude()` becomes:

```golang
got, _ := c.cParseIncluder().parseInclude("x")
```

See [Go plaground](https://play.golang.org/p/pc9G3u_Uyt) and click on `Run`: no more `initialization loop`.

---

The [OP Red Skotina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5790890/red-skotina) used a different approach with an [package `init()` function](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#init):

```golang
var gProxy grammar

func init() { gProxy = g }
func parseInclude(fileName string) (interface{}, error) {
    got, _ := ParseReaderProxy(fileName)
    return got, nil
}
func ParseReaderProxy(filename string) (interface{}, error) {
    p := &parser{filename: filename}
    return p.parse(gProxy)
}
```

Comment: thanks. i break cycle with

    var gProxy grammar
    func init() {
       gProxy = g
    }
    func parseInclude(fileName string) (interface{}, error) {
        got, _ := ParseReaderProxy(fileName)
        return got, nil
    }
    func ParseReaderProxy(filename string) (interface{}, error) {
        p := &parser{filename: filename}
        return p.parse(gProxy)
    }

your answer is other way but seems better.

Comment: @RedSkotina That would work too indeed. I have included your approach in the answer for more visibility (and proper formatting)